# Codename one: Dont allow to create dual app on same device

Tags: mobile, codenameone

I have created app using codename one which can be installed on same device two times with dual app features which provided by android.
I dont want to allow my app to install multiple time on same device so I want that my app should not support that dual app feature so what should i do for that?can you help me to solve this problem?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be an Android feature but rather a vendor customization. As far as I can tell the whole idea is to hide the fact that this is the same phone from the app developer so there is probably no easy way to detect this.

If you find native Android code that detects it I can explain how you would do this in Codename One.